# XCode doesn't archive unity build

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, core-location

I am trying to push a unity app to the app store (this is a first for me).

Unity builds the project fine, however when I import it in XCode, Archiving or building doesn't work.

The problem occurs when precompiling Prefix.pch
I need to use the geolocalization of the device in order to run my app.
I think that is what creates the framework related issues I am getting (it seems that the errors are in the APK and not in my code).
There files that are giving me errors are located in ios15.5>Frameworks>CoreLocation
I suppose CoreLocation is not imported ?

[image: BuildResultErrors]

I did however try to Embed the CoreLocation framework in the Targets>General Tab like so but I have no idea if that is the way to do it:
[image: CoreLocationEmbedding]

I am definitely missing something but I don't know what to do at this point.

I am trying to do this using a mac mini with Monterrey OS, XCode 13.4, unity 2021.3.7.
My target os is iOS14.

If someone could give me some advice it would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

It seems this question was already answered [here](https://github.com/ryanw3bb/unity-native-toolkit/issues/35):

In the files generated by the unity builds, in
Libraries>Plugins>iOS>NAtiveToolkit
there are files named Locale.h and locale.mm that are conflicting with the Locale.h file of the project.

Renaming them to LocaleTools.h and LocaleTools.mm seemed to do the trick

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).